Why plpython functions increase transaction counter much more then plpgsql functions?
I'm trying to understand why plpython function has much bigger impact on transaction counter in Postgres than plpgSQL function. Below is example which uses 2 functions:
Vesion with plpgSQL (each part done in separate transaction one ofter another)

check txid_current
sql query which calls f1_plpgsql function  which calls insert_row_to_db function. It happes 100 times
check txid_current

Them we compare values for txid_currnent values and difference is 2 which means that whole sql with 100 calls to f1_plpgsql and insert_row_to_db increased transaction counter only by 1.
Here is code:
CREATE TABLE insert_rows_table(
    i BIGINT
);


CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insert_row_to_db(i BIGINT)
RETURNS VOID
AS $$
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO insert_rows_table SELECT i;
END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql SECURITY DEFINER VOLATILE PARALLEL UNSAFE;


CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f1_plpgsql(i BIGINT)
  RETURNS bigint
AS $$
BEGIN
    PERFORM insert_row_to_db(i);
    RETURN i;
END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql SECURITY DEFINER VOLATILE PARALLEL UNSAFE;


SELECT txid_current();
SELECT f1_plpgsql(i::BIGINT) FROM generate_series(1,100) as i;
SELECT txid_current();

Example output:
txid_current
500

f1_plpgsql
1
2
...
99
100

txid_current
502

Here is code reproduction on db-fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4jyoMCicNSZpjMt4jFYoz5/15135
Now let's replace f1_plpgsql with function written in plpython:
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f1_plpython(i BIGINT)
  RETURNS bigint
AS $$
    rows = plpy.execute("SELECT insert_row_to_db(" + str(i) + ")")
    return i
$$ LANGUAGE plpython3u SECURITY DEFINER VOLATILE PARALLEL UNSAFE;

Example output:
txid_current
500

f1_plpgsql
1
2
...
99
100

txid_current
602

Which proves that plpython function affects transaction counter much more. Does anyone knows why? Is there anything I can do about it?
What's interesting it happens only if the function called by Plpyhon makes changes to DB. If we replace INSERT INTO insert_rows_table SELECT i; with SELECT i both plpython and plpgsql behave the same.


For Postgres 13+ txid_current() is deprecated, you should start using pg_current_xact_id (). 2) Your output does not match your code e.g. you are showing 1..100 when you are using generate_series(1,10). 3) In what client are you running this code? In other words does it have autocommit on?



I verified that using pg_current_xact_id instead of txid_current doesn't change anything.  2) You are right that I forgot to change the numbers in the generated series. At the last minute, I decided to change 10 to 100 to make it more obvious where the problem is.   3) This problem was noticed at first with SQL executed by Python via psycopg2 but then I reproduced it with this example via DBeaver. And yes DBeaver has autocommit but that has nothing to do with the problem, as I can switch it to manual transactions and get the same result.

